# Julia: Immutable composite types

Tags: hash, julia

I am still totally new to julia and very irritated by the following behaviour:

```
immutable X
  x::ASCIIString
end

"Foo" == "Foo"
true
X("Foo") == X("Foo")
false
```

but with Int instead of ASCIIString

```
immutable Y
  y::Int
end

3 == 3
true
Y(3) == Y(3)
true
```

I had expected `X("Foo") == X("Foo")` to be true. Can anyone clarify why it is not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Julia have two types of equality comparison:

1. If you want to check that **x and y are identical, in the sense that no    program could distinguish them.** Then the right choice is to use `is(x,y)` function, and the equivalent operator to do this type of comparison is `===` operator. The tricky part is that two mutable objects is equal if their memory addresses are identical, but when you compare two immutable objects `is` returns true if contents are the same at the bit level.

`2 === 2 #=> true, because numbers are immutable`

`"Foo" === "Foo" #=> false`

2. `==` operator or it's equivalent `isequal(x,y)` function that is called *generic comparison* and returns true if, firstly suitable method for this type of argument exists, and secondly that method returns true. so what if that method isn't listed? then `==` call `===` operator.

Now for the above case, you have an immutable type that do not have `==` operator,  so you really call `===` operator, and it checks if two objects are identical in contents at bit level, and they are not because they refer to different string objects and `"Foo" !== "Foo"`

- [Check source Base.operators.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/operators.jl).
- [Read documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/base/#Base.is)

EDIT:

as @Andrew mentioned, refer to Julia documentation, Strings are of immutable data types, so why `"test"!=="true" #=> true`? If you look down into structure of a String data type e.g by `xdump("test") #=> ASCIIString  data: Array(UInt8,(4,)) UInt8[0x74,0x65,0x73,0x74]`, you find that Strings are of composite data types with an important `data` field. Julia Strings are mainly a sequence of bytes that stores in `data` field of String type. and `isimmutable("test".data) #=> false`

Comment: I'm a little confused, you say that strings are mutable, but [the string documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/strings/) says that "As in Java, strings are immutable".

Comment: I made a mistake `isimmutable("test") #=> true`, the answer needs edit

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. That not only explains the behaviour but also shows how one goes about finding this out. So I suppose to achieve the behaviour I expected one would have to explicitly define

Comment: [...] `==(x1::X,x2::X) = x1.x == x2.x`. I misread "Collections typically implement isequal by calling isequal recursively on all contents." in the documentation (http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/) as the default implementation for collection types. But in fact by default `X("Foo") == X("Foo")` is `X("Foo") === X("Foo")` too. So thank you again for the very nice explanation.