# Julia dictionaries : not always unicity of dictionary keys with immutable keys

Tags: dictionary, key, julia

In Julia 0.6, struct are immutable, so I expected the functions func1(), func2() and func3() which feed a dictionary with struct keys to produce only one record:

```
Dict(KEY("Bob", "NY", "[120 10]")=>true)
```

but this is not the case, when I put a String in a variable of the key struct, the key is unique and when I use the same Strings directly, the keys are not unique. Even more strange, if I produce the variables x,y,z with split in func3(), the keys produced from the variable are not unique.

Since it is very easy to have a bug with these subtleties, I show a simple example here :)

```
struct KEY
    A::String
    B::String
    C::String
end


function func1(d::Dict{KEY, Bool})  
    for i = 1:3
        x = "Bob"
        y = "NY"
        z = "[120 10]"
        d[KEY(x,y,z)] = true
    end
end

function func2(d::Dict{KEY, Bool})   
    x = "Bob"
    y = "NY"
    z = "[120 10]"
    d[KEY(x,y,z)] = true
    d[KEY(x,y,z)] = true
    d[KEY("Bob","NY","[120 10]")] = true
    d[KEY("Bob","NY","[120 10]")] = true
end

function func3(d::Dict{KEY, Bool})  
    for i = 1:3
        str = "Bob;NY;[120 10]"
        (x,y,z) = split(str, ";")
        d[KEY(x,y,z)] = true
    end
end

function  main()
    d = Dict{KEY,Bool}()
    func1(d)
    println("func1 ", d)
    d = Dict{KEY,Bool}()
    func2(d)
    println("func2 ", d)
    d = Dict{KEY,Bool}()
    func3(d)
    println("func3 ", d)
end

main()
```

The output is:

```
func1 Dict(KEY("Bob", "NY", "[120 10]")=>true)
func2 Dict(KEY("Bob", "NY", "[120 10]")=>true,KEY("Bob", "NY", "[120 10]")=>true,KEY("Bob", "NY", "[120 10]")=>true)
func3 Dict(KEY("Bob", "NY", "[120 10]")=>true,KEY("Bob", "NY", "[120 10]")=>true,KEY("Bob", "NY", "[120 10]")=>true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** `KEY` is immutable, as are `String`s but strings are a "composite data type" and thus have a `data` field which IS NOT immutable. As a result of this the different KEY/keys you have added actually have different hashes.

```
a = KEY("fg","g","gh")
b = KEY("fg","g","gh")

a == b # false
# because a == b falls back to a === b

a === b # false
# because hashes are different
Base.hash(a) == Base.hash(b) # false

# because even though
isimmutable(a) & isimmutable(a.A) & isimmutable(a.B) & isimmutable(a.C) # true
isimmutable(a.A.data) # false
a.A.data[1] = 0x70
println(a) # KEY("pg","g","gh")
```

More explanation here: [Julia: Immutable composite types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070366/julia-immutable-composite-types) and the source at [base/operators.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/operators.jl).

Answer (score 2):

I post this as an answer, because I think it is important and the answer will live longer than Julia 0.6 (although the comment is short).

This behavior is fixed on Julia 0.7. When you run `main()` you will get:

```
func1 Dict(KEY("Bob", "NY", "[120 10]")=>true)
func2 Dict(KEY("Bob", "NY", "[120 10]")=>true)
func3 Dict(KEY("Bob", "NY", "[120 10]")=>true)
```

as expected.

The reason is that in Julia 0.7 if `s1` and `s2` are `String`s containing the same data (not necessarily at the same memory location) we have that `s1===s2` is `true`.

Here is a link to the code performing the comparison: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/src/builtins.c#L181.

Also already in Julia 0.6 `String` does not have `data` field.